# Why mapping a GeoTIFF world map in QGIS at low zoom level (0～2) results in a strange behavior?

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, mapping, rendering

I have created a GeoTIFF world map,

but I notice that it cannot be rendered correctly at zoom level which are low (e.g. zoom level 0, 1, 2).

[image]

Is it a predicted behavior or how can I fix this?

[I also recorded a Youtube video for demonstration](https://youtu.be/2-AOWXv3vGg)

Update：
There is a screenshot the same GeoTIFF file mapping at zoom level 5 (scale 1：18524092).
I think under this scale, it's mapping well.

[image]

Comment: There's no zoom levels in QGIS, there're scales. Which scale range are you talking about? Which CRS are you using?

Comment: looks like a CRS mismatch

Comment: @Erik thanks for reply. I use the plugin show the zoom level conversion at QGIS status bar ,  scale like 1:295829344(level 1.0) or  1:147914672(level 2.0), the CRS of tiff file is GWS84 (epsg 4326), QGIS canvas CRS I tried are WGS84 and Spherical Mercator (epsg 3857)

Comment: @IanTurton thanks for reply. I think QGIS will do the CRS on the fly transform automatically, and if I try to zoom in at high zoom level(scale zoom in over 1:147914672), the mapping result is pretty good.

Comment: QGis can only do the reprojection if the two layers are correctly projected to start with and I don't think they are.

Comment: @IanTurton I update a screenshot, i think projection setting is ok, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be the [bug described here](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/34518) or something similar. It affects raster layers when the bounding box is bigger than the raster layer. When you zoom in, everythin is perfect.

This behavior is common for my QGIS installations on different machines with EPSG:4326 as project CRS (not 3857 as in your case), see screenshot with rasters in the same CRS (4326) as project:
[image]

Strange enough, setting the project CRS to 3857, leaving the rasters at 4326, it works well:

[image]

Apart from disturbing visually: is there a reason you want to change that? You need this small scale view? From my experience, this affects only visualization, not processing. So a workaround is to just ignore it. If you really need such small scale visualizations, you should reproject or change you project CRS. Fixing the bug - or [funding it's fixing](https://blog.qgis.org/category/qgis-funding/) - would be a nice alternative: https://qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/donations.html#

Comment: Thanks for your help, babel. I am just using GeoTIFF for mapping on web, QGIS is useful for checking and viewing mapping result before uploading result to the web.